# How to send a string instead of bytearray in python via USB port?

Tags: python-3.x, pyserial, labview

In labview, I convert an array to string and just output it:

[image: block diagram extract]

But in python 3.6, when I use `serial.write(string)` function, string needed to be turned into a `bytearray`.

Is there anyway I can send a string without convert it to `bytearray`?

Comment: post full code you've tried as "working" example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No.**

A Python 3.x string is a sequence of [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters) code points. A Unicode code point is an abstract entity, a bit like the colour *red*: in order to store it or transmit it in digital form it has to be **encoded** into a specific representation of one or more bytes - a bit like encoding the colour *red* as `#ff0000`. To send a string to another computer, you need to encode it into a byte sequence, **and** because there are many possible encodings you might want to use, you need to specify which one:

```
bytesToSend = myString.encode(encoding="utf-8")
```

**Why didn't you need to do this in LabVIEW?** Many older programming languages, including both LabVIEW and Python before 3.x, are based on the assumption that strings are encoded 1:1 into bytes - every character is one byte and every byte is one character. That's the way it worked in the early days of computing when memory was tight and non-English text was unusual, but it's not good enough now that software has to be used globally in a networked world.

Python 3.x took the step of explicitly breaking the link and making strings and byte sequences distinct and incompatible types: this means you have to deal with the difference, but it's not a big deal, just `encode` and `decode` as necessary, and in my opinion it's less confusing than trying to pretend that strings and byte sequences are still the same thing.

LabVIEW is [finally catching up with Unicode](https://forums.ni.com/t5/NI-Blog/Designing-LabVIEW-NXG-How-Unicode-Benefits-You/ba-p/3886228?profile.language=en) in the NXG version, although for backward compatibility it lets you get away with wiring strings directly to some functions that really operate on byte sequences.

For more information I recommend reading the [Python 3.x Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html).

Comment: LabVIEW NXG strings are Unicode, and the separation of string type from byte array type was modeled on Python. @nekomatic How do you see them differing? Please expand on that in your answer as it seems highly relevant.

Comment: @srm I guess I'm referring to the way the linked article discusses how strings are stored as UTF-8 (I don't know or care how Python stores them) and the fact that VISA/TCP/UDP functions for example can still work with strings, which perhaps encourages the idea that a string is still kinda sorta the same as a byte sequence. I appreciate that not doing this would break more existing code and it's a legitimate design choice. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I pulled down the latest release. Latest NXG release has byte arrays for the TCP/UDP terminals by default, with a configuration option to switch over to text mode, which changes the terminals to strings. The default install doesn't have VISA, as far as I can tell, so I can't check that.